# VisualCode - Float object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to create a solution to a problem regarding maximum floors and I cannot run the program without Visual Code saying "float" object is not iterable. What does this even mean?
EDIT: The solution that works is:

```
def gps(s, x):
    if len(x) < 2:
        return 0
    a = max(x[i] - x[i-1] for i in range(1, len(x))) 
    return a * 3600.0 / s
```

I am trying to not use list comprehensions as it is a bit difficult for me to understand. I am essentially converting it.

```
   def gps(s, x):
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return 0
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        a = max(x[i] + x[i-1])
    return (3600 * a)/s
print(gps(15,[0.0, 0.19, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25]))
```

Comment: What's `max(x[i] + x[i-1])` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @KrishPatel if you have a new problem, please close this question and post a new one.

Comment: I already changed everything to talk about the new problem. He was referring to something else in which I changed.